# React-redux: TypeError: _this2.props.handleCityChange is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm implementing a weather widget in react-redux, I'm getting error "TypeError: _this2.props.handleCityChange is not a function" and similar errors for all functions. I've gone through the redux docs, plenty of google searches and similar stackoverflow questions and I still can't understand where the problem is, at this point I'm willing to try almost anything.

I've removed most of the code to reduce snippet size for the question, keeping only a small part to explain the problem, let me know if you need the full code and I'll update it.

Here's the Container,

```js
import { isChangingCity} from '../actions/weather.act'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    status: state.weather.weather.status,
    tempFormat: state.weather.format,
    temp: state.weather.weather.temp,
    isFetching: state.weather.isFetching,
    isChangingCity: state.weather.isChangingCity
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    handleCityChange: () => dispatch(isChangingCity(true)),
        });

const weather = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Weather)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

and the Component,

```js
import React from 'react'

class Weather extends React.PureComponent{
render(){
 return(
 <span>
  <button className = "btn btn-light" onClick={() => this.props.handleCityChange()} >
      Change City
    </button>
     </span>
     );
    }
}
export default Weather
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

All help is appreciated.

Comment: i think it could be the same problem as this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48138715/connected-component-not-receiving-props/48138863#48138863, let me know if it solves your issue or not

Comment: Ayush where is the dumbComponent connected to container.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Yes, that works, can you write your comment as an answer so I can mark it as correct? Also, is this considered a duplicate question, if so do I delete it or leave it as is?

Comment: In that case, its a duplicate of the of the other question, you could leave this question as it is. Also consider upvoting the other question and the answer that helps you

Answer (score 0):

```js
import React from 'react'
import container from "pathToContainer"
class Weather extends React.PureComponent{
render(){
 return(
 <span>
  <button className = "btn btn-light" onClick={() => this.props.handleCityChange()} >
      Change City
    </button>
     </span>
     );
    }
}
export default container(Weather)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @ayush provide the path to container and check if it works.

Comment: No, it doesn't, now I'm getting the error 'You must pass a component to the function returned by connect. Instead received undefined' . Removing the import solves the error.

Comment: From container just export the connect(mapStateToProps, mapDisptachToProps) function